# How to include js files in the view. ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I wonder why my js file work when I call it in the view:

```
@section Scripts {  
<script>   

    function myFunction() {
        alert("Hello1");
    }       

</script>
}
```

but does not work when I call it:

```
@section Scripts {

   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Views/Home/script.js"></script>
   <script>   
         myFunction();
    </script>
}
```

Comment: These both look like `Razor` files? Is the top file the _Layout and the second a view using the layout?

Comment: I'm working in the view. But with "@ section Scripts" I want the script to be placed in the _Layout when run in the browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's because  `.js` files are not accessible in the `~/Views/` folder. You have to [enable it](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/j-tower/2014/03/28/loading-javascript-files-from-the-views-folder-in-asp-net-mvc).

To enable access to `.js` files in the Views folder, you can add the following to your Views' folder's web.config directly under the `handlers` tag:

```
<add name="JavaScriptHandler"
         path="*.js"
         verb="*"
         preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

Alternatively put your script into the `~/Scripts/` folder and reference it like such:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/script.js")
```

Comment: Just a sidenote... I actually put my scripts in the Views folder. I do something like having `Views/Home/Contact.cshtml` and nested underneath the file in visual studio (using the [NestIn](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45) extension) I have `Views/Home/Contact.js` and `Views/Home/Contact.less`. Then my build script picks up the files appropriately. It's actually a great time saver to do this.

Comment: David, can you elaborate about what your build script does? I like this idea too, I am passing a lot of time struggling and looking for related files...

Comment: @codea sorry, that was confusing. Since I have a build script that minifies and concatenates my scripts, instead of having it search the scripts folder for scripts—`~/Scripts/**/*.js`—it searches the Views folder instead—`~/Views/**/*.js` since they are now stored in there.

Answer (score 10):

Its better practice to place your Js file in Script folder and access it from there. You could write this code in view's head to use the js file

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/script.js")
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to add your script in the Bundle config :

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",    "~/Views/Home/script.js"));
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You should Add rendersection to your Layout Page which your view using.

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```