# JavaScript is not Working on the Other Page But Works on the Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I've written a JavaScript code in the textbox so that only numbers can be entered. The javascript code works fine on the page below but it does not work when I move it to GeneralJS.js page.

This is my GeneralJS.js:

```
function numberControl(event) {
    if (event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 0 && (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57))
        return false;
    var frm = document.getElementById("numeric_form");
    orm.setAttribute("onsubmit", true);
    return true;
}
```

I call the GeneralJS.js page on the layout.

And this is my Add.cshtml:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="numeric_form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TCNo" min="0" maxlength="11" value="@Model.TCNo" style="width: 230px;" onkeypress="return numberControl(event)" />
</form>
```

This is my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/js/GeneralJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: spelling mistake i think, line 5 shouldnt 'orm' be 'frm'?

Comment: I changed but the same problem persists.

Comment: do you have the link to the GeneralJS.js file?

Comment: Yes I call it on the layout page.

Comment: Did you include GeneralJS in your html file.

Comment: Setting attributes to elements is not a proper event attaching, use [`addEventLlistener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead, or use the jQuery event model, since you've tagged the question with jQuery.

Comment: I think we need more info so we don't get more answer trying to guess the problem? could you share the error you're getting in the browser console? could you share how you're adding the script to the page?

Comment: I do not get any errors. It works when I write the javascript code to the Add.cshtml page but the JavaScript code does not work when I write it on the GeneralJS.js page. Therefore, letters can be entered in the text box.

Comment: Show us how you are registering the script file in your page

Comment: Can you check please, I add.

Comment: Check out my answer @Shadouspan

Answer (score 0):

I think fixing that typo might well have worked, but you are refreshing a cached version of your GeneralJS.js file. Clear your browser cache and try again.

If that hasn't worked, append something like ?version=1.1 to the .js file path reference, and that will bust the cache.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript Use `$(document).ready( function(){  });` on the `general.js` page
For Jquery Use `on('load',function(){ })`

Answer (score 0):

The `~` (that indicates root) won't work in that context. It's something that the `Scripts.Render` uses. An easy fix would be make that URL absolute.

```
<script src="/Content/Scripts/js/GeneralJS.js"></script>
```

There are more recipes available, for instance, you could register an static file using `Scripts.Render`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24763515/2373249).