# Angular 2 - TypeScript File not resolving to .js extension .NET MVC Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular

**Background**

I am migrating one of the apps from Angularjs 1.x to Angular 2. Being new to the Angular 2 , I am first trying to get grasp of different files used for configuration

Before jumping to my app, I created a small dummy app with the help of quickstart files from Angular Quickstart on gitub

[https://guthub.com/angular/quickstart](http://github.com/angular/quickstart)

I move those files into a .NET MVc 5.0 web app. When I build the app using the npm CLI

```
npm start
```

It creates an index.htm, and that successfully ran. My next step was to use a MVC View instead of this index.htm, This time, I created a default route for  localhost/ pointing to PublicController with a view Index.cshtml.

**Problem Statement**

While using MVC views, routed through Controllers, what I see is that main.ts file when compiled omits the file extension - *.js For e.g.

```
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
```

in my Main.ts, when compiled translates to (in main.ts)

```
var app_component_1 = require("./app.component");
```

My page ran with a console error, and I saw 404 error for not been able to resolve app.component.

All works out fine, If I manually type in **.js in my main.js** file. But that's not the solution.

```
var app_component_1 = require("./app.component.js");
```

**Question**
Which setting should I change and which file that should resolve filename in the main.ts to filename.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include js files in the view. ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763493/how-to-include-js-files-in-the-view-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: @Aaron Rumery : That's the not problem. This is angular specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found the solution.. problem is with the dot in the file name , Issue is reported here too https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/756

I added the following setting in the ***systemjs.config file***

```
packages: {

          '.': {
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
```